# To find the minimum and maximum corresponding value in between a range of clubbed values

Tags: excel-formula

I am having a small issue with writing a formula. I have my data in this format :

```
NAME  |  EXP     |     SALARY

A     |  0.3     |      40000

B     |  4.7     |     490000

C     |  2.6     |     220000

D     |  3.9     |      34000

E     |  1.3     |     150000

F     |  3.2     |     300000

G     |  0.8     |      90000

H     |  1.9     |     170000

I     |  2.1     |     260000

J     |  4.1     |     390000
```

this is what i want in my output :

```
EXP-RANGE  | MIN SALARY  |  MAX SALARY

0-1

1-2

2-3

3-4

4-5
```

i want to find the minimum and maximum salary of people in the experience range
i tried using MIN(IF(<&>)) but it returns #VALUE?

i can also push all this data in to a Database and query it but I would greatly appreciate anyone who could formulate it so that i can work on Excel itself. Data size is 20000+ so i wouldn't prefer filters

Thanks in advance

Comment: so if someone has 1 year of experience are they counted in both ranges?  if only one range, which range does 1, 2, 3 and 4 belong to?

Comment: i will prefer the upper range.1 belongs to1-2, 2 belongs to 2-3 and so forth. Thanks for the edit Ed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MAXIFS and MINIFS:

```
=MINIFS(C:C,B:B,">="&LEFT(G2,FIND("-",G2)-1),B:B,"<"&MID(G2,FIND("-",G2)+1,LEN(G2)))
=MAXIFS(C:C,B:B,">="&LEFT(G2,FIND("-",G2)-1),B:B,"<"&MID(G2,FIND("-",G2)+1,LEN(G2)))
```

[image]

---

If one does not have MAXIFS or MINIFS we can use AGGREGATE:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,7,$C$2:$C$11/(($B$2:$B$11>=--LEFT(G2,FIND("-",G2)-1))*($B$2:$B$11<--MID(G2,FIND("-",G2)+1,LEN(G2)))),1)
=AGGREGATE(14,7,$C$2:$C$11/(($B$2:$B$11>=--LEFT(G2,FIND("-",G2)-1))*($B$2:$B$11<--MID(G2,FIND("-",G2)+1,LEN(G2)))),1)
```

AGGREGATE is an array type formula and the references should be limited to the data set.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner . I dont seem to have MINIFS or MAXIFS, thank you for including the Aggregate option!

Comment: can you please explain this part :  MID(G2,FIND("-",G2)+1,LEN(G2)

Comment: @SandeepNair `MID(G2,FIND("-",G2)+1,LEN(G2)` if finding `y` from `x-y` in your EXP RANGE.

Answer (score 0):

Assume "Lookup table" put in `A1:C11`

Criteria with header in `G1:G6`

In `H2` (Min wage), formula copied right to `I2`(Max wage) and all copied down:

```
=AGGREGATE(14+(COLUMN(A1)=1),6,$C$2:$C$11/($B$2:$B$11>=IMREAL($G2&"i"))/($B$2:$B$11<-IMAGINARY($G2&"i")),1)
```

Edit : In convert the criteria "`0-1`" to complex number "`0-1i`", the IMREAL() extract the left side number "`0`", and the IMAGINARY() extract the right side number "`1`"

=AGGREGATE(`14+(COLUMN(A1)=1),`6,..., return in Column K =AGGREGATE(`15`,6,….) and column L =AGGREGATE(`14`,6,….)